How to allow Buildozer Dist Requirements to download? ssl error: certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)
While working in WSL Ubuntu 20.04.6 I am encountering a SSL Self-Certification error while using Python3.8 and java-8-jdk .
I am running Buildozer to create an APK file from a python file.
I have followed the Buildozer document steps on: https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to initialise and build for android.
Successfully creating the buildozer.spec file.
The next step, to create the APK using buildozer -v android debug has caused a lot of issues, the most prominent being SSL Self certification errors.
This prevented the download of the android-ndk-r25b-linux.zip.
I managed to download and set up the ndk folder successfully thanks to this post: How to install android ndk in linux?
Despite this now working, the issue appeared again when building the recipes.
The error appears to stem from the python library urllib.
The files are being downloaded from github, pypi.org and others.
I can download the .tar and .zip files fine manually but cannot do it through the natural Buildozer means, which leads to issues further into the install.
I have tried the following:

exporting the location of the cacert.pem file locally and in the .bashrc:
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=~/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem

Adding the cacert.pem file to /etc/ssl/certs/

Disabling python verification, locally and in the .bashrc
export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0


I was expecting to have a .apk file placed in the /bin dir of my project home ~/project/bin but this error appears:
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/<user>/<project>/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/packages/hostpython3
[DEBUG]:   -> running basename https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.5/Python-3.11.5.tgz
[DEBUG]:        Python-3.11.5.tgz
[DEBUG]:   Downloading hostpython3 from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.5/Python-3.11.5.tgz
[DEBUG]:   -> running rm -f .mark-Python-3.11.5.tgz
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython3 from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.5/Python-3.11.5.tgz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 1344, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1331, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1377, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1326, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1085, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1029, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1472, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1042, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1320, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)

